# iPhone - Work with subfolder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, detailsview

I am having a tableView which lists the contents directory which includes jpg, pdf, zip, mp3, mp4, sql,.. files and even folders. In the next step, I am having a detailView which displays some properties of the selected file such as fileName, fileSize, filePath, fileType. Everything works perfect.

But actually I have included an additional option in the detailView.

That is,

1. If the selected file in the tableView is a image file, it opens an imageView in the detailView to display that image.
2. If the selected file is a mp3, it opens a player to play the song in the detailView.
3. If the selected file is a video or mp4 file, it opens a player to play that video in detailView.
4. For other files, it pushes an alertView regarding that it is an unknown file.

(and I got stuck here..) 5. If the selected item is a folder, it should again open a tableView which displays the contents of the folder.

That is, it should open the subfiles and subfolders in a tableView which should be a recursive function. Please help me to do this..

I think my screen shots may give some ideas.

This is my tableView listing the contents of my directory..

[image]

where "SQLTutorial" is a folder in the above list

This is the detailView of an image file

[image]

This is the detailView of a video file

[image]

This is the detailView of an audio file

[image]

Please help me to complete the process with some sample codes to view the folders and subfolders in a tableView. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Paul answer, you can add a 'folder' ivar and define it when the row is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  FolderViewController * detailViewController = [[FolderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourTableView" bundle:nil];

  UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  // Set the title of the navigation item for the table view
  detailViewController.folder = cell.textLabel.text;
  detailViewController.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel.text; 

  // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  [controller.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best thing will be to show the folder name as part of the initial list (your first image) and, when selected, you'll create a new list with the folder's content and push it to a navigation controller.

You'll probably need to refactor your table view to have an ivar which contains your "path" and add, if you don't already have, a navigation controller.

Comment: Thank you.. Can you brief the second part?

Comment: When i select the folder "SQLTutorial" in the tableView, it should navigate to a tableView pushing its contents. May I have any source code for this method?

Answer (score 0):

If the files and folders are loaded in viewDidLoad of the view controller, so the easiest way is adding a property to your view controller to indicate the source folder. So when the user touches subfolder cell, you can init new view controller, set the property to that subfolder and push it to navigation controller.

Comment: Can u help me with a source code to push a tableView when the folder is selected?

Comment: When i select the folder "SQLTutorial" in the tableView, it should navigate to a tableView pushing its contents. May I have any source code for this method?